# GWT: How to run server-side only code?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm working on a GWT+GAE project in Eclipse.

I would like to execute some server-side only code e.g. I would like to run an algorithm which generates and stores data in the GAE Datastore.

What is best practice to run the code?

Comment: Can I just start the GWT server by Run as -> Web Application and then run a main function in a Java class in the server package by Run as -> Java Application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the app engine scheduled tasks.

Quoting "The App Engine Cron Service allows you to configure regularly scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals. These tasks are commonly known as cron jobs. These cron jobs are automatically triggered by the App Engine Cron Service. For instance, you might use this to send out a report email on a daily basis, to update some cached data every 10 minutes, or to update some summary information once an hour."

The documentation is located at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

If there is no need to have an scheduled tasks you can use the task queue.

The documentation is located at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue

Comment: Assuming  I use this method, I have to start a cron job manually by using cURL.Is this the best practive for my use case, even if I run my tasks only manually?

Comment: To configure cron job in app engine you add an cron.xml that get auto configured when you deploy your project.